# AWS : Why Elasticache and RDS require a VPC whereas Elasticsearch and DynamoDb don't

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Currently, building a serverless app that use DynamoDb and Elasticsearch is quite easy

Using serverless, you just declare everything in serverless.yml and you are good to go

Problems (quickly) arise when you need to use RDS or Elasticache because you have all kind of troubles with VPCs...which then simply defeats the serverless paradigm (developper should only focus on code)

The quickest solution is then to use a 3rd party solution (like RedisLabs or ClearDb)

My question is : why RDS and Elasticache require the VPC mode ? why aren't they usable directly like a 3rd party service ?

EDIT : as noted in the comments, you can place DynamoDB and Elasticsearch behind a VPC .

The problem then becomes : how to efficiently access them (RDS, elasticache, dynamodb, elasticsearch) from a lambda function ?

You need to configure the VPC of the lambda function to access all the other VPCs as described in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html

Also, consider that the lamba also needs to access 3rd party services on the internet (ex : sendgrid, onesignal, ...) so I think that you still need a NAT somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best article I found on the subject : http://blog.brianz.bz/post/accessing-vpc-resources-with-lambda/

It explains nearly everything about VPC access from lambda (from what is a VPC, why you need it, how to access from lamdba and to configure from serverless)

Answer (score 2):

The distinction here is where the resources are actually running. Both Elasticsearch and DynamoDB are managed services running outside of your AWS account. RDS and Elasticache are different - they are launched into your AWS account, hence the need to tell AWS where you want to run them.

By the way, RDS doesn't require VPC. You can optionally run it in EC2-Classic or in EC2-VPC. And those are the only options to run compute on AWS (either in VPC, or not in VPC), so you are not actually being constrained here. You are simply being asked which you prefer.

The solution for access to private resources in your VPC (like RDS databases) is to configure the Lambda function to run in that VPC. Now the Lambda function is essentially inside the VPC, so it is constrained by the VPC's networking configuration. For the Lambda function to reach external websites, it needs a route to the public internet. Typically the way you do this in VPC is to configure an IGW and some form of NAT (roll-your-own, or managed NAT from AWS). This is all normal VPC behavior, and not specific to Lambda.

Comment: I am constrained when I want to access those RDS instances from lambda : i need to configure the lambda to run inside the RDS VPC (and then, my lambda cannot access elasticsearch without configuring NAT...) Or am I wrong ?

Comment: @ChristopheBlin I believe you are incorrect about ElasticSearch. 
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-vpc.html  DynamoDB also can be configured with a VPC Endpoint (otherwise you'd need a NAT device for that, as well, with Lambda inside a VPC).  Note that you can also configure a t2.nano instance as a NAT device instead of a NAT Gateway, if you need low-cost NAT for a VPC.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks for your answer but I think there is a misunderstanding about my question so I have edited it. What I need in the end is a lambda function (a set of lambda function more precisely)  that is able to access both VPCs and the internet at the same time